# background color is not visible when i insert the background image of same color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the background and the background image of down arrow of same color. when i call the background image then the background color gets hide.i have the background color and the background image of same color.

```css
.customer-bg{
 background: #e1efcc url(../img/bottom-arrow.png) no-repeat center bottom ;
}
.customer-bg p{
 font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 color:#666;
 padding: 30px 7px 60px 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="customer-bg">
      <p>
       Semper ac dolor vitae msan. Cras interdum hendreritnia vitae molestie interdum.
      </p>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use shorthand background property like this **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/my21uqou/)**

Instead of this:

```
.customer-bg{
        background: #e1efcc;
        background: url(../img/bottom-arrow.png) no-repeat center bottom ;
    }
```

Use:

```
 .customer-bg{
        background: #e1efcc url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/f/f/d/1194985689770236807arrow_-_next_01.svg.med.png) no-repeat center bottom;
    }
```

Still if your bg image is not displayed, check the image path :)

**Update:**

As per your requirement I tried this **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/my21uqou/2/)** with green color down arrow icon..

Hope this helps !!

Comment: using these i am getting the background color but not bg image

Comment: did you saw my demo? I added some arrow image for your reference.. If bg image is not displayed, then check the image path

Comment: ya got it but the image is getting behind the background how to bring it at the bottom??

Comment: ya i have updated the code and i am getting the bg image and i need to bring it down because the image and the bg-color are of the same color. so how to bring the image down to the bottom?

Comment: i dont have the live image but i used these image http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/arrow-point-to-down_32209#term=down-arrow&page=1&position=4 of same background color

Comment: but the arrow should start from the end of the background color

Comment: Harsh, without seeing your output / sharing your image.. its difficult to give solution.. I can suggest you to make a try by changing the background position :)